# Run stored procedure on each child element

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

I have this xml:

```
<Root>
<Child>
<a>1</a>
<b>2</b>
</Child>
<Child>
<a>3</a>
<b>4</b>
</Child>
<Root>
```

I **have** a stored procedure ("spChild") which accepts child element and takes care of it.

I **need** to write a stored procedure that calls "spChild" on each "`<Child>`" element. That stored procedure accepts the whole xml above.

What is the best way to do it ?

I've tried to do it like this:

```
WHILE @currentChildItemIndex <= @countChildItems
    BEGIN
            SET @ChildItem = @DataInXML.value('data(/Root/Child[.= sql:variable("@currentChildItemIndex ")])[1]' ,'int')
        EXEC @returnValue = MyDB.dbo.spChild @childXML

        SET @currentChildItemIndex = @currentChildItemIndex + 1
    END
```

Comment: What is not working for you? How do you fill `@countChildItems`? You are extracting a value from the XML to `@ChildItem` but you are using `@childXML` as a parameter to the SP, why is that?

Comment: Hey, I'm having trouble with the xpath line. Is it the best way doing it ? I know WHILE isn't efficient..

Comment: Ok, there is no way to not use a while loop but I still don't understand what you want the parameter to your SP to be. You are trying to fetch an int value from the XML but your text says you want the child element. What is it? Why do you have both `@ChildItem` and `@childXML`? Do you need both? Where do you populate `@childXML`? If you want the XML for a child instead of a value you should use `.query()` instead of `.value()`.